# Forgot Password in cognito (if email is not verified)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am trying **forgot password** flow with Cognito. But users who didn't verify the email aren't getting a verification code for forgot password. I have checked other StackOverflow posts as well but it is suggested to verify the user's email which will be the wrong way as it is not verified after all.

```
var userData = {
    Username: email,
    Pool: awsConfig.cognitoUserPool
};
var cognitoUser = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser(userData);    
    cognitoUser.forgotPassword({
            onSuccess: function (data) {
                // console.log(data);
                resolve(data);
            },
            onFailure: function (error) {
                reject(error);
            }
        });
```

Comment: What use case are you trying to implement here?

Comment: @AleksanderWons my use case is if a user registers and without clicking on verification link if he clicks on forgot password it won't send the verification code in email because it send to only verified mail. it is a corner case but yet is failing in my scenario

Comment: So, you won't be able to do what you want with Cognito. And it kind of makes sense. Since the user never confirmed the ownership of the account why would she/he be able to change the password?

Comment: Okay @Aleksandra

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a late post, but I have a solution for you.
Reset password would send a confirm code to the verified email. But if the email is not verified, it will be caught in the catch block of the async function. During this, send the verification link again to the email address provided (you can use Amplify's resendSignup -> https://aws-amplify.github.io/amplify-js/api/classes/authclass.html#resendsignup). This is because Cognito sends password confirm code ONLY to verified email addresses.
Hope this helps you and other devs having similar issues. A code example is given below:

```
const handleSubmit = async () => {
setIsLoading(true)
const isError = handleInputValidation()
if (isError) {
  setIsLoading(false)
  return
}
try {
  await requestCode(input.email)
  setIsLoading(false)
  history.push({
    pathname: path.auth.resetPasswordAwait,
    state: input.email,
  })
} catch (error) {
  if (error.message.includes('verified')) {
    await resendSignUp(input.email)
    setErrorMessage(
      'Your email is not verified. A new verification link is sent to your email. Please confirm your email address.',
    )
  } else {
    setErrorMessage(error.message)
  }
  setIsLoading(false)
}
```

}

Comment: Important: the prevent user existence errors must be false, otherwise an error will not be thrown.

Comment: Thanks @EdmundoSantos , I just want to add that the 'Prevent user existence errors' option can be changed in the app client configuration of the user pool.